# return statement inside fs.readFile causing Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, fs

i have simple `fs.readFile` function to read json file data, get one of it's properties (array) and check if that array contains every single element of user generated array, and i use this code for this purpose

```
const contains = (arr1, arr2) =>
   arr2.every(v => arr1.indexOf(v) !== -1)

 fs.readFile('../tags.json', 'utf8', (err, data)=>{

    if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: err.message});

   var JsonData = JSON.parse(data);
   var tagsArray = JsonData.tags;
   console.log(tagsArray)
   console.log(tags)
   if(tagsArray instanceof Array){
     console.log('tagsArray is array')
   }
   var bool = contains(tagsArray, tags)
   if(!bool){
      return res.status(409).send({
        message: 'don't provide your own tags'
      })
   }

 })
  const user = await User.findById(req.userId, '-password').lean()

 const book = await Dish.create({
    //properties
 })

 return res.status(200).send({var: JSON.stringify(book)})

 } catch (error) {
     return res.status(500).send({
       message: error.message
     })
   }
```

i have try catch block inside the function (router.post) where `fs.readFile` is but it still gives me this message:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
>   block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

and also this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: Well where is the promise rejection coming from? You dont show the code where the error is originating.

Comment: After calling this function do you call res.send?

Comment: yes but with 200 status code & in try catch block with 500 status code

Comment: You can only call res.send once so your error is because you call res.send a second time

Comment: @GifCo console pointing me to a line where catch() is but i am sure problem is with this block because if i delete it code starts working

Comment: @IdsvanderZee yes you are right but i call res.send with return statement so it must stop executing code if error occurs

Comment: Well if thats where the error points it would probably make sense to show that code.

Comment: show what code? catch block? `catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send({
      message: error.message
    })
  }` here it is

Comment: you call return in this function therefore you return back to the function where you called this function, then you try to call res.send again which results in an error.

Comment: @IdsvanderZee check out edit, how can i fix it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 const contains = (arr1, arr2) =>
   arr2.every(v => arr1.indexOf(v) !== -1)

 let match = false;
 fs.readFile('../tags.json', 'utf8', (err, data)=>{

   var JsonData = JSON.parse(data);
   var tagsArray = JsonData.tags;
   console.log(tagsArray)
   console.log(tags)
   if(tagsArray instanceof Array){
     console.log('tagsArray is array')
   }
   match = contains(tagsArray, tags)   

 });
 const user = await User.findById(req.userId, '-password').lean()

 const book = await Dish.create({
    //properties
 });

 if(!match){
    return res.status(409).send({
      message: 'don't provide your own tags'
    });
 }

 return res.status(200).send({var: JSON.stringify(book)})


 } 
 catch (error) {
     return res.status(500).send({
       message: error.message
     });
 }
```

You can try this, this should only call res.send once, either with 200, or 409, or 500 status codes.